# Extracting date from a string in a multidimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, string, date, multidimensional-array

I am having a hard time with a part of my homework.

Basically, I have user to input some data for x people in 2Darray (name, last name, id, salary). 
ID is a string of 13 numbers being **ddmmYYYY**XXXXXX (x is not important for this part of the task). I need to extract the IDs from every array in the list, and place them in a separate array (I have done this), and make it a valid date format (*dd.mm.YYYY*).
How do I edit the string in such way?

here is my code so far:

```
counter = 0
workersList = []
totalSalaries = 0
datesOfBirth = []

#1
workersNumber = int(input("How many? "))

#2
for i in range (workersNumber):
    workersList.append(input("Name, Last name, ID and salary ").split(" "))    
    datesOfBirth.append(workersList[i][2])

#3
    if len(workersList[i][2])==13:
        #print("Good ID number")
        totalSalaries = totalSalaries + float(workersList[i][3])


#4
        avgSalaries = totalSalaries/workersNumber
        counter+=1




#5
print("List of workers: ")
for j in range (workersNumber):
    print(workersList[j])
    print(datesOfBirth)


#6


#7


#8
```

I know how I can change entire string, but I can't know what user will input, so I need this string to be separated with a dot after the second, fourth and seventh character. How do I do it? I will easily rstrip the rest.

Comment: It's not 100% clear to me what do you want. Do you want to verify that the data user inputs is in valid format?

Comment: I want to take the string ddmmYYYYxxxxxx and change it to dd.mm.YYYY.xxxxxx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its very simple, Just replace the line in Step#2

```
datesOfBirth.append(workersList[i][2])
```

with

```
datesOfBirth.append('.'.join([workersList[i][2][0:2],
                              workersList[i][2][2:4],
                              workersList[i][2][4:8]]))
```

'**.**' is your delimiter and We are slicing elements

> ddmmyyyy
>   [0:2][2:4][4:8]

Comment: I have actually made a mistake, my id goes ddmmYYY, so it's [0:2][2:4][4:7]. So I need to put "1" before YYY part, or "2" if YYY<100, but that is my problem :) thank you Rahul.

Comment: Glad to Help! Once you have enough experience with Python you should start using the code @sam-stafford Sam Stafford suggest as it is a more pythonic way. Try to learn List Comprehensions in python.
Apart from making the code more readable and concise, list comprehension has noteworthy advantage, performance. Yes, the execution time for list comprehension is much faster as compared to the normal method of appending to the list.
Go through this link as it has pretty amazing explanation with examples.
https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension

Answer (score 3):

Slicing+formatting is a pretty easy way:

```
worker_data = [
    input("Name, Last name, ID and salary ").split()
    for _ in range(int(input("How many? ")))
]
worker_dobs = [
    f"{id[0:2]}.{id[2:4]}.{id[4:8]}"
    for [_first, _last, id, _salary] in worker_data
]
```

This is assuming that the data is valid; if you need to handle invalid data, I'd suggest replacing the `input("Name, Last name, ID and salary ").split()` with a function that does the appropriate validation so it gets weeded out before it goes into the `worker_data` list.

Once you have your list of data, it's easy to derive other useful values from it; you don't need to do it as you're building the list.  For example:

```
from statistics import mean

average_salary = mean(
    float(salary)
    for [_first, _last, _id, salary] in worker_data
)
number_workers = len(worker_data)
```

etc.

Comment: I have already split the string into an array list. I got string id for every worker in a new array. Now I need to edit the string, so that ddmmYYYYxxxxxx become dd.mm.YYYY.xxxxxx

Comment: Did you try running the code I gave you?  It does exactly that.  Just print out those values.

Comment: I am still trying to clarify to myself what you did here, and where should I put it. Can you explain the statistics part for me please?

Comment: It's computing the average salary (which is why the variable is called `average_salary`) using the `mean` function from the `statistics`module.  `mean` generatics the statistical mean of whatever you pass into it (the sum of all values divided by the number of them), similarly to the `avgSalaries` in your example code, but it just does it automatically.  The `float(salary) for [_first, _last, _id, salary] in worker_data` is an iteration over `worker_data` that destructures it into its four values, grabs `salary`, and converts it to a `float`.